# Prove the inequality $|1+x|^p \ge 1+px+c_p\varphi_p(x)$

Tags: analysis, inequality

> Show that $|1+x|^p \ge 1+px+c_p\varphi_p(x)$, where $c_p$ is a constant depending only on $p$.
>   $$\varphi_p(x) := \begin{cases}|x|^2 & |x| \le 1\\ |x|^p\  & |x| >1 \end{cases}$$
>   if $1<p\le2$, and $\varphi_p(x)=|x|^p$ on $\mathbb{R}$ if $p>2$.

This question is alike the binomial theorem 
$$(1+x)^p>1+px+\frac{p(p-1)}{2}x^2$$, for $p>1$ etc. But $\varphi_p(x)$ varies to the values of $x$ and $p$. How do I prove the above?

Comment: What if you take $c_p=0$?

Comment: This contradicts the fact that $c_p$ varies to $p$.

Comment: It won't change the fact that $c_p$ is a function of $p$.

Comment: Then what if $c_p \neq 0$?

Answer (score 0):

I think we have that $p \geqslant 1$.
By Bernoulli's inequality, we have that $\forall x\geqslant-1$:
$$(1+x)^p \geqslant 1+px$$
And if
$$0\geqslant1+px$$
We have that
$$|1+x|^p\geqslant 0 \geqslant 1+px$$
So we need to work on the case when $-1\geqslant x\geqslant -\frac{1}{p}$. But since $p \geqslant 1$, we have that $\frac{1}{p} \leqslant 1$, so $-\frac{1}{p}\geqslant-1$.
So $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have that
$$|1+x|^p \geqslant 1+px$$
Your $\varphi_p(x)\geqslant 0 \forall x$, so the inequality
$$|1+x|^p \geqslant 1+px +c_p\varphi_p(x)$$
Will remain true $\forall c_p \leqslant0$.